# Throw statement in JavaScript gives "undefined undefined" output

Tags: javascript

Anytime I try using the throw statement in a `try/catch` command.
It gives me an output of `undefined undefined`.
Please how can I make it work.

Here is the code I used

```js
try {
  let a = prompt("Answer");
  if (a == 10) {
    throw "right";
  } else {
    throw "wrong"
  }
} catch (i) {
  alert(i.message);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where this happens?

Comment: Please I've edited my question and add the code.

Comment: @CirLom. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple errors:

- You have to convert the result to a number before the comparison, you can use the [Number function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
- You have to show the error and not only its message property since you are throwing a string and not an object.

```js
try {
  const a = Number(prompt('Answer'));
  if (a === 10) {
    throw 'right';
  } else {
    throw 'wrong';
  }
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```