# Unexpected 'undefined' output from 'throw' statement

Tags: javascript, undefined, throw

I wrote a simple function to check if the passed parameter is 0, positive, or negative. I know for a fact that the passed parameter is a number and not any other data type. I am getting `undefined` as output while I expect the text provided in the throw statement to be printed in case the passed parameter is a zero or a negative number.

1. I already checked the question at [Throw statement in JavaScript gives "undefined undefined" output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640496/throw-statement-in-javascript-gives-undefined-undefined-output) ,
   and that does not solve my issue.
2. I also tried defining an Error object as in:

   ```
   ZeroError = new Error ("Zero Error");

   NegativeError = new Error ("Negative Error");
   ```

and then using those errors as parameters to 'throw':

```
throw ZeroError;

throw NegativeError;
```

and I get the same `undefined` output for both zero and negative values.

Here is my function:

```
function isPositive(a)
{
    if (a === 0) throw "Zero Error";
    if (a < 0) throw "Negative Error";
    if (a > 0) return ("YES");
}
```

While I am getting "YES" as output when a > 0, I am getting `undefined`
when a is zero or negative. I expect "Zero Error" when a is zero, and "Negative Error" when a is negative.

Comment: Where are you calling `isPositive`? Where do you get the output you describe from, are you logging something somewhere?

Comment: may be you are using `let` ??

Comment: Slightly beside the point, but note that you should generally be `throw`ing Error objects instead of strings (like `throw new Error('Zero Error')`)

Comment: @jlaitio: I tried that too, and I get 'undefined'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#Exception_handling_statements

Comment: @axiac: Already aware of that, and have gone through the details.

Comment: It's quite funny that I get -4 for my genuine question which I am trying to get answer from experts as to why it is happening!

No wonder StackOverflow is regarded as a user-unfriendly place!

Comment: @VenkatRamakrishnan the difference between `throw` and `return` is something basic. You should learn about it in any JavaScript tutorial. Your question is not a real problem and you can probably find dozens of similar questions on SO. That's why it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

`throw` doesn't not return anything, it throws an exception, replace it with `return` and you'll get your value.

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

EDIT: If you need to catch the exception, look into `try/catch`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

```
function isPositive(a) {
    if (a === 0) throw "Zero Error";
    if (a < 0) throw "Negative Error";
    if (a > 0) return ("YES");
}

let result; 
try {
   result = isPositive(0);
} catch (e) {
   if (e === "Zero Error") result = "Zero Error";
   if (e === "Negative Error") result = "Negative Error";
}
```

Comment: I have a specific need to throw an exception in case of zero or negative.

Comment: then your code will need to try/catch - show how you're using `isPositive`

Comment: Then you need to add a `catch` and handle it there

Comment: What has 'catch' to do with getting 'undefined' output?

Comment: @VenkatRamakrishnan I've added a usage example.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
function isPositive(a) {
    try {
        if (a < 0) {
            throw "Negative Error"
        } else
            if (a == 0) {
                throw "Zero Error";
            } else {
                return "YES"
            }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

1. Need to have try-catch
2. It's important to return the error from the catch. That return
   of error will solve the 'undefined' return.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
function isPositive(a) {
    if(a>0) {
        return 'YES';
    }
    if (a===0) {
        throw new Error("Zero Error");
    }
    else if (a<0) {
        throw new Error("Negative Error");
    }
}
```

Not sure what the problem with using throw, just the way it is. Later when I do find the actual reason I'll add it here.

https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

Optimized solution for the problem. I hope it clear to everyone :)

```
function isPositive(a) {
    try {
        if (a == 0) throw 'Zero Error';
        if (a < 0) throw 'Negative Error';
        return 'YES';
    } catch (throwedErrorMessage) {
        return throwedErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Positive(a)
{
  try { 
    if (a === 0)
      throw "Zero Error";
    if (a < 0) throw "Negative Error";
    if (a > 0) return ("YES");
    document.write("hello")
  }
  catch(err) {
   document.write("hello");
}
}
Positive();
```

Comment: Edited the answer to modify the 'document.write' part to returning the error.